# What does if [[ $# -ge 1 ]] mean in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I was going over some files and found this:

```
if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]
```

What does that mean?

Comment: That's a silly way to write things. `if (( $# >= 1 ))` is more readable, or `if [ "$#" -ge 1 ]` is more portable; `if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]` combines the disadvantages of both, being neither readable (by folks who know math syntax from C/Java/etc) nor portable (to baseline POSIX-compliant shells).

Comment: BTW, answering this kind of question is what http://explainshell.com/ is built for.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Except explainshell apparently can't understand `[[` though I don't see why it shouldn't. And it doesn't understand `((` correctly either, treating it as a sub-shell. I always want it to be more useful than it actually seems to be in practice.

Comment: great, I can see downgrading.. Guys, I didn't write it on my own.. i just encountered it somewhere and didn't understand, tried Googling it but failed.

Comment: Can anybody explain the difference between `[[` and '['?  That's the part that confused me.

Answer (score 19):

if the number of passed parameters is greater than or equal to 1

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Got it.

Answer (score 5):

In shell script $# stores the number of arguments passed from the command line, like *argc in c programming.

So, By using the "if" statement we are verify the number of arguments are greater than or equal to one.

Answer (score -1):

> It means:

if param_numbers >=1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).